How to reach goal pose with less than 5cm of error in Nav2
I'm trying to use nav2 to move a diff-drive robot to a follow a path to a goal pose with less than 5cm of distance error and 5 degrees of angular error. Unfortunately, all local plannars I have tried fail to do this. For example, the default xy goal tolerance for the DWB controller is 0.25 (25cm) which is much too high for my use case. If I simply reduce the tolerances, the controller frequently becomes stuck and fails to make progress. I am working in simulation with perfect odometry, so I expect it be to easy to achieve high goal pose precision, but this does not appear to be the case. I also need a local planner that considers the robot's footprint for collision avoidance. My DWB params are shown below. Any advice on what I can do to achieve centimeter-level goal pose precision?
controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    # controller server parameters (see Controller Server for more info)
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    progress_checker_plugins: ["progress_checker"] # progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker" For Humble and older
    goal_checker_plugins: ["goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.05
      stateful: True
    # DWB controller parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: -0.26
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.26
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 50
      vy_samples: 20
      vtheta_samples: 50
      sim_time: 3.0
      linear_granularity: 0.01
      angular_granularity: 0.01
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.1
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist", "ObstacleFootprint"]
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.5
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.5
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

And here are the logs from the controller server:
[component_container_isolated-4] [INFO] [1713438586.992707840] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438586.992893569] [controller_server]: No controller was specified in action call. Server will use only plugin loaded FollowPath . This warning will appear once.
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438586.992949319] [controller_server]: No goal checker was specified in parameter 'current_goal_checker'. Server will use only plugin loaded goal_checker . This warning will appear once.
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438586.992982558] [controller_server]: No progress checker was specified in parameter 'current_progress_checker'. Server will use only plugin loaded progress_checker . This warning will appear once.
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438587.204201994] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[parameter_bridge-2] [INFO] [1713438587.232243646] [ros_gz_bridge]: Passing message from ROS geometry_msgs/msg/Twist to Gazebo gz.msgs.Twist (showing msg only once per type)
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438587.372406517] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438587.540548736] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438587.707380277] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438587.869304731] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438588.039337700] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438588.215151604] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438588.388007967] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438588.556401882] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438588.720881841] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438588.893504279] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438589.075069703] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438589.251127093] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438589.433021163] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438589.616323218] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438589.806862180] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438589.999430683] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438590.190051506] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438590.392071131] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438590.594647660] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438590.794333054] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438591.002475294] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438591.211393906] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438591.434224700] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438591.653278274] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438591.869671663] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438592.094063127] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438592.345231140] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438592.612798116] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438592.903956771] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438593.183041163] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438593.494322737] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438593.857910754] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438594.176233248] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438594.539202021] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438594.919507930] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438595.309375638] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438595.830473847] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438596.355522862] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438596.862956854] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438597.395089412] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438597.960947031] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438598.578732208] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438599.101980022] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438599.605986343] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438600.094824276] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438600.581909102] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438601.080771920] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438601.619100461] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438602.098730627] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438602.242537515] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438602.379870438] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438602.515051473] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438602.657637050] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438602.797680953] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438602.939652055] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438603.079056724] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438603.215805014] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438603.350914157] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438603.487791896] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438603.627915765] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438603.768512177] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438603.912494398] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438604.051091353] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438604.188672689] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438604.328255071] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438604.473737650] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438604.619189133] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438604.761671937] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438604.902847221] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438605.054331439] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[component_container_isolated-4] [ERROR] [1713438605.055608695] [controller_server]: Failed to make progress
[component_container_isolated-4] [WARN] [1713438605.056651741] [controller_server]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.


The goal checker has nothing to do with your controller plugin. The goal checker is invoked by the controller server no matter which planner plugin you use. So the question is why would the controller server ignore your parameters. Make sure you actually receive the logging statements and see if everything works as expected. Alternatively, see what happens when you use the StoppedGoalChecker instead. Also, it may be useful to know what your tree looks like.

I don't think the parameters are ignored. It's just that the robot often fails to make progress and aborts the goal when I set the tolerances too low.

Using the StoppedGoalChecker still results in the same problem.

Based on the comments and plugging your set of parameters in a test environment I see the same behavior. The bot first gets stuck midway and the goal gets aborted.
To fix that I simply adjusted the progress checker to be less aggressive and give the controller more time
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.2
      movement_time_allowance: 20.0

The same can be achieved by increasing velocity limits and let the bot achieve its goals faster.
Then, the bot did not achieve the goal precisely. I managed to fix that by adjusting the critics weights. Since you are working with a diff-drive bot, rotating to the goal heading can be done anytime, so turn down the scale. You are mainly interested in sticking close to the planned path during approach and close the remaining distance to the goal, so crank up those weights. These are just quick estimates that worked, so tweak to your use case.
RotateToGoal.scale: 10.0
PathAlign.scale: 50.0
GoalDist.scale: 100.0

Also make sure that your plugin xy_goal_tolerance is low enough but about your linear_granularity. It will stop when being within this distance to the goal. You can also increase the min_vel_x if you don't want the bot to slow down.

Thanks for this. I will try it and confirm if it works or not.

I am struggling a lot to find parameters that work robustly,  but I agree with your opinion that this is the right approach. Thanks.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but how about separating precision control from general control? Navigate "coarsly" with a sophisticated controller doing collision avoidance. Then do the precision control with a much more generic controller and straightline and align to goal) without any critics and so on? That is pretty easy to achieve with the nav2 plugin system, I think it would only require to extend the tree you are running.

I am computing a global plan outside of nav2. I want the nav2 "FollowPath" behavior to follow my global plan, bringing the robot to the goal pose with the smallest error possible. The trajectory to the goal pose is allowed deviate slightly from the global plan so long as it avoids collisions and achieves the goal pose preciesly.
